# Scripting speed test for formatting a string

Tags: ruby, string-formatting

I am formatting a phone number, and there can be no single digit after a dash, i.e. `123-555-5555` or `12-34`, but not `123-4`. There can also be any alpha characters in the answer.

[Here](https://github.com/JLWolfe1990/puzzles/blob/master/phone_fun.rb) is my answer.

```
class CodeTestException < Exception; end

# driver method
def phone_format(s)
  string = s.to_s.gsub(/[^0-9]/, '') # force input to string
  string_length = string.length

  # ensure that the return type stays consistent and make sure that there isn't
  # one digit by itself as specified by the API
  return string unless string_length > 2

  format_phone_string(string, string_length)
end

private

def format_phone_string(string, string_length)
  formatted_string = ""
  early_dash = string_length % 3 == 1
  skip_dash = false

  # start index at 1 for easier comprehension
  i = 0

  string.each_char do |char|
    formatted_string << char
    break if i == string_length

    i += 1

    formatted_string << '-' && skip_dash = true if early_dash && (i == string_length - 2)

    formatted_string << '-' if i % 3 == 0 && !skip_dash
  end

  formatted_string
end

raise CodeTestException unless phone_format("(+1) 888 33x19") == "188-833-19"
raise CodeTestException unless phone_format("555 123 1234") == "555-123-12-34"
raise CodeTestException unless phone_format("(+1)") == '1'
raise CodeTestException unless phone_format(nil) == ""
raise CodeTestException unless phone_format("") == ""
```

I was told that the answer was not recursion, or scan. I believe `O(n)` is the best time that I can make. Some other solutions that I found was a higher multiple of linear time. Can anyone beat my solution?

Comment: Please include a code snippet

Comment: Ok! I've went ahead and added it inline for you. I'm sorry that it took me so long to respond. For some reason I didn't receive an email update of your comment! @SaraTibbetts

Comment: Questions that do not ask for a solution to a concrete programming problem are off-topic on [so]. However, our sister site [codereview.se], was specifically created for questions like this. But please, do make sure that you read their tour, FAQ, on-topic, and off-topic pages (linked on the bottom of the page) before you post. Also, just like on [so] and any other site in the Stack Exchange network, all relevant information (in this case your code) must be part of the question, not hidden behind external links.

Comment: Thank you kindly. I've been using SO for years, but this is my first post. I will close this issue, if possible, and move it over there! Thank you for your patience.